# How to install Selenium selenium-java-3.141.59 library on Eclipse or Netbeans?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, java-8, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using JDK 1.15.0.1 and Java version 8.
In conjunction with the Selenium library from [here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) I've also been using the Chrome driver from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=88.0.4324.27/)

I've tried all the tutorials I could find on the web and can't figure out how to install the latest Selenium WebDriver library successfully.
I've primarily followed [this tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/installing-selenium-webdriver.html) (and ones similar to it) as closely as possible with slight variation for each attempt after the first to no avail.
Eclipse keeps indicating that my program isn't registering the library or importing the packages within correctly by stating the it "cannot find symbol [class from selenium library]" upon hovering over the associated class usages in the test code.

I've tried a similar approach and similar tutorials with the same files in the Netbeans IDE with the same result.

Here's the test code I've been using:

```
package internet.bot;

/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
public class InternetBot {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //for the web driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\GitHub\\Internet-Bot\\Internet Bot\\src\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    }
}

/*Sources
Example Google Search code:                             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640972/how-to-have-java-application-interact-with-a-website

*/
```

Edit: I think I should also mention that the selenium library I downloaded doesn't have as many .jar files as the one shown in the tutorial [referenced](https://www.guru99.com/installing-selenium-webdriver.html).

Comment: you'll just want to add the necessary jar files to your project... these should show up in your project under "libs" after you add them.  Then add your imports.  In Netbeans I think it's alt-enter when cursor is on red-lined text... (it should suggest adding an import line and add it automatically...)  There is nothing to install... you're just adding dependencies.

Comment: @pcalkins I think that might be on the right track!
I have no idea why it wouldn't let me import the packages before, but it seems when I did the alt+enter thing it let me import them without any difficulty!
The only issue now is it doesn't seem to be recognizing the chromedriver.exe file as an executable.
I'm kind of new to this, can this be answered here or should I make a new question for it?

Comment: nevermind @frianH helped me resolve the rest, thank you for your help, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### *Eclipse

I'm trying to suggest configure your project with Maven, this is easier.

After you have created a project, right click on it.

Select **Configure** > **Convert to Maven Project** > **Finish**

It will automatically generate the `pom.xml` file.

[image: configure to maven]

**Note** : Here, make sure you are connected to the internet.

After that, please add the selenium dependency according to the version you want between the closing `</build>` and closing `</project>` like bellow:

**pom.xml**

```
  ....
  ....
  </build>
  
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
</project>
```

Save and the project will build automatically, and wait a few moments for the workspace to finish configuring.

Comment: I just tried that and it gave me the same problems, here's what I did:
1 followed steps 4 onward from the tutorial linked in the original question
2 followed your instructions
3 saved all files and then waited a little
4 tried importing packages as some of the quick-fix recommendation popups offered to no avail
5 restarted eclipse to no avail

I checked and double checked to make sure that I did things correctly.

Comment: the same as before in Eclipse, but @pcalkins' answer seems like it might have gotten it working in Netbeans only it doesn't seem to be recognizing the chromedriver.exe file as a driver executable, returning `read "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\...`
I'm kind of new to this; can this be answered here or should I make a new question for it?

Comment: @Isaac Are you sure `chromedriver.exe` is in that path? Or try to change the path to be simpler like `C:\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe`, please put binary at this path.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can go for a Mavan project, its better when upgrading/downgrading the versions and the plugings

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately it didn't work